# Counter example: $X$ and $Y$ normal imply $(X,Y)$ bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I vaguely remember this construction from one of my courses:

Suppose that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Z$ is $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. If $X$ and $Z$ are independent, then $Y\equiv XZ$ is $N(0,1)$. Quick proof:
$$
\Pr(Y\leq y)=\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X\leq y)+\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X\geq-y)=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(y)+\frac{1}{2}(1-\Phi(-y))=\Phi(y)\tag{$\star$}
$$
because $\Phi(-y)=1-\Phi(y)$. Then $U\equiv X+Y$ is $2X$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Because $U$ has a mass of size $\frac{1}{2}$ at $0$, $U$ cannot be normally distributed and so $(X, Y)'$ is not bivariate normal.

**My question**: how does one compute the CDF of $U$? I'm trying to do something like ($\star$) but I keep making mistakes.

---

**Edit**: I'll write my attempt there. For $u\geq 0$,
$$
\Pr(U\leq u)=\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X\leq u/2)+\frac{1}{2}1=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(u/2)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot
$$
For $u<0$,
$$
\Pr(U\leq u)=\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X\leq u/2)+\frac{1}{2}0=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(u/2).
$$
Does that look right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{P}(U \leq u) = \mathbf{P}(X+Y \leq u) = \mathbf{P}(X+Y\leq u, Z = 1) + \mathbf{P}(X+Y \leq u, Z = -1) = \mathbf{P}(2X \leq u, Z=1)+\mathbf{P}(0\leq u, Z=-1) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{P}(X\leq \frac{u}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{0 \leq u}.$

There you see the jump discontinuity at $0$.

EDIT: Now I see you edited your question. Your calculation is correct.